# Best practices for REST resource's property level permissions

Tags: rest

Imagine, you have resource such resource returned by REST API at `/api/catalogs/1`:

```
{
  items: ['item1', 'item2'],
  details: ['1', '2', '3']
}
```

Imagine, you want to restrict access to some response fields for some users. For example restrict access to `details` field.

Question: which response format is the best in this case?

Option 1 - omit field.

```
{
    items: ['item1', 'item2']       
}
```

Option 2 - return nulled field.

```
{
    items: ['item1', 'item2'],
    details: null       
}
```

Any another options?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your needs.

But if the API consumer shouldn't know about the existence of a particular property (or don't have access to it), it makes more sense to *omit it* rather than *returning* `null` *values* (once it may cause misunderstanding on the API consumer).

Answer (score 1):

I think you should avoid to display that `details` exist unleast it serve a real purpose for consumers. So ommit that field.